# Refactoring logic in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, refactoring

Currently I have a ton of logic in my view for a campaign/show.html.erb:

```
<% if current_account.active? %>
  <% if @campaign.pending? %>
    <%= render 'campaigns/dashboard/nulldashboard' %>
  <% elsif @campaign.disabled? %>   
    <%= render 'campaigns/dashboard/disableddashboard' %>
  <% elsif @campaign.stats? %>   
    <%= render 'campaigns/dashboard/livedashboard' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'campaigns/dashboard/awaitingdatadashboard' %>
  <% end %>
<% elsif current_account.pending? %>
  <%= render 'campaigns/dashboard/awaitingactivation' %>
<% end %>
```

and in my model:

```
  def active?; status == :active; end
  def finished?; status == :finished; end
  def pending?; status == :pending; end
```

My question is, how would I go and clean up this code? I'm pretty new to rails and not quite sure how I would go about this.

Thanks much!

Comment: Is the entire view or only a portion of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a view model - some people call it a page object.

I can't quite make out what your purpose is, but say that you want to render different dashboards depending on some different inputs:

```
class DashboardPage
  attr_reader :account, :campaign

  def initialize(account, campaign)
    @account, @campaign = account, campaign
  end 

  def render_dashboard?
    account.active? || account.pending?
  end

  def dashboard_template
    if account.active?
      active_account_template
    else
      'campaigns/dashboard/awaitingactivation'
    end
  end

  private

  def active_account_template
    # the inner if goes here...
  end
end

# In your controller

@page_object = DashboardPage.new(current_account, @campaign)

# In your view

<% if @page_object.render_dashboard? %>
  <%= render @page_object.dashboard_template %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: See also presenter pattern http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/03/rails-presenter-pattern.html